# How can (dy/dx) = (1/(dx/dy)) be true when isolating different variables and differentiating them indicates this isn't the case?

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation, inverse-function-theorem

Let $y=x^3$.
We know that...
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=3x^2
$$
The derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$ is $3x^2$. Everyone can agree on this. But what if we were to isolate the other variable?
$$
y=x^3
$$
$$
\sqrt[3]{y}=\sqrt[3]{x^3}=x
$$
$$
\sqrt[3]{y}=x
$$
And now if we decide to take the derivative of $x$ with respect to $y$,
$$
\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{1}{3x^{2/3}}
$$
$\frac{1}{\frac{dx}{dy}}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{3x^{2/3}}}=3x^{2/3}$, which is not equal to $\frac{dy}{dx}=3x^2$. So...$\frac{dy}{dx}$ is not $\frac{1}{\frac{dx}{dy}}$? What am I missing here? Shouldn't this violate the [Inverse Function Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3726541/1106401)?

P.S I know you're supposed to implicitly differentiate...but what I'm interested in is why the above procedures don't yield the same results as implicit differentiation (correctly) does.

Comment: Derivatives aren't really fractions. It's just a useful comparison when using the chain rule.

Comment: It is $\frac{1}{3y^\frac23},$ not $\frac{1}{3x^\tfrac23}$.

Comment: You should put that as an answer ...

Comment: @insipidintegrator oh my god. you are absolutely right. this is what always thinking of x as the input variable does to a person

Comment: To just expand, the *inverse function* of $f(x)=x^3$ is $f^{-1}(x)= \sqrt[3]x$.

Comment: I have revised it back to the original because editing the question to replace the x with y basically takes away the understandability (is that a word?) and relevance of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that $y=x^3$, hence $$\begin{cases} \frac{1}{dx/dy}=3y^{\frac{2}{3}}\\
y=x^3\end{cases}\implies \frac{1}{dx/dy}=3x^2=\frac{dy}{dx}.$$